# Neo4J Cypher - Is it quicker to load from 100k Json Files or 1 file with 100k entries?

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am performing a daily load of 100k+ json files into a neo4j database which is taking approximately 2 to 3 hours each day.

I would like to know whether neo4j would run quicker if the files were all rolled into one large file and then iterated through by the database?

I will need to learn how to do this in Python if so, but I would just like to know this before embarking on the work.

Current code snippet I use to load files, the range can change each day based on generated filenames which are based on IDs in the json records.

```
UNWIND range(215300000,215457000) as id
WITH DISTINCT id+"_20220103.json" as file
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///output/"+file,null, {failOnError:false})
YIELD value
```

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming the single file will not exceed the memory size. The single file will be better because it will reduce the number of file IO operations, In both cases, the database has to do the same amount of work.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply! 
OK yes, this makes sense to me thank you.
Today there are 142k files which total 683mb. I imagine the size of all the data combined into one won't be significantly different, I will have to go and experiment now :-)

Comment: Best luck! Even if a single file doesn't fit into memory you can experiment and come up with a size or number of entries for each file.

Comment: In any case, look into apoc periodic fuctions for batching, depending on the updates you could also run parallel updates with apoc periodic iterate

Comment: The python script was recoded to bundle all json into one file and the cypher was recoded to iterate thru them. It now loads in  2 or 3 minutes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json construction in Python was updated to include all 150k+ json objects into one file and then Cypher was updated to iterate over the file and run the code against each json object. I initially tried a batch size of 1000 and then 100 but they resulted in many exception locks where the code must have been attempting to update the same nodes at the same time, so I have reduced the batch size down to 1 and it loads about 99% of the json objects on a first pass in 7 minutes.... much better than the initial 2 to 3 hours :-)

Code I am now using:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
'CALL apoc.load.json("file:///20220107.json") YIELD value',

'UNWIND value as item.... perform other actions...   
',{ batchSize:1, parallel:true})
```